# How to copy back the uninstalled files into the same location using bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, uninstallation

I am uninstalling a software using an uninstall string running from a batch file. It uninstalls the software successfully and deletes the data files stored in `C:Test\Data`.

I want to copy back the data file into same location after uninstalling but its not copying back the `Data` folder.

If I run the batch file after removing the uninstall string, it works as expected.

I'm Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
if exist "C:\Test\Data" (
    mkdir C:\TempMPC
    start /wait /b xcopy  C:\Test\Data C:\TempMPC /S /I /Y /R
    rem wait for a moment
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak > nul
)

"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{2EA86967-B3D3-4B2E-9DE9-28A595AF2E2E}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0409 -removeonly /s /f1
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul

// THis is not working but if I delete the above command it works
if exist "C:\TempMPC" (
    if not exist "C:\Test\Data" (
        mkdir  C:\Test\Data
    )
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak > nul
    start /wait /b xcopy /S /I /Y /R C:\TempMPC C:\Test\Data
    rem wait for a moment
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
)
```

Thanks Gerhard for your input, I tried in this way:

```
@echo off
if not exist exist "C:\Test\Data" goto :eof
mkdir "C:\TempMPC">nul 2>&1
robocopy "C:\Test\Data" "C:\TempMPC" /S /I /Y /R

start "" /wait "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\InstallShield Installation Information\{2EA86967-B3D3-4B2E-9DE9-28A595AF2E2E}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0409 -removeonly /s /f1"%~dp0\uninstall.iss"

if not exist "C:\TempMPC" goto :eof
mkdir  "C:\Test\Data">nul 2>&1
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > nul
robocopy "C:\TempMPC" "C:\Test\Data" /MIR
```

Where `uninstall.iss` is the response file to bypass user input during uninstall and uninstall is successful. Copying back is not happening. However if I delete the below line of code then it works fine.

```
start "" /wait "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\InstallShield Installation Information\{2EA86967-B3D3-4B2E-9DE9-28A595AF2E2E}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0409 -removeonly /s /f1"%~dp0\uninstall.iss"
```

Comment: Firstly, what is the reason you `start xcopy`? on the other hand you don't start the uninstall executable? There is no reason to check if the folder exists.. just do `md "c:\Test\Data">nul 2>&1`

Comment: I would also just rather use `robocopy` simply something as: `robocopy "C:\TempMPC" "C:\Test\Data" /MIR`

Answer (score 0):

Untested, please try this instead:

```
@echo off
if not exist exist "C:\Test\Data" goto :eof
mkdir "C:\TempMPC">nul 2>&1
robocopy "C:\Test\Data" "C:\TempMPC" /MIR

start "" /wait "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\InstallShield Installation Information\{2EA86967-B3D3-4B2E-9DE9-28A595AF2E2E}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0409 -removeonly /s /f1

if not exist "C:\TempMPC" goto :eof
mkdir  "C:\Test\Data">nul 2>&1
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > nul
robocopy "C:\TempMPC" "C:\Test\Data" /MIR
```

Comment: I tried this but same result it copied to TempMPC but copy back is not working

Comment: ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "/I"

Comment: My shell got exited after running the command
   start "" /wait "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\InstallShield Installation Information\{2EA86967-B3D3-4B2E-9DE9-28A595AF2E2E}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0409 -removeonly /s /f1"%~dp0\uninstall.iss"

Comment: `robocopy "C:\Test\Data" "C:\TempMPC" /S /I /Y /R` should be `robocopy "C:\Test\Data" "C:\TempMPC" /MIR`

Comment: Looks like issue is not with copy, my cmd promt exiting after executing uninstall command

Comment: the one you showed works fine as standalone without uninstall command, but with uninstall command it exits CMD after Uninstall command

Comment: How does it exit if the command is staryed outside of the cmd? Can you show a screenshot please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220019/discussion-between-sijith-and-gerhard).